# How would I bind this to the onclick event in JQUERY?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom, events

I have the following which i use in a traditional onclick event for a DIV tag

How would I go about implementing this using jquery?

```
$parameter = "onClick=\"selprice('" .
  $price_options_array[$price_counter]['price'] . "','" .
  $price_counter . "')" . "\"";
```

I use the above and just add it to my div like so:

```
<div class="price_row" <?php echo $parameter; ?>>
```

I have this so far using the jquery method but Im not sure how to proceed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.price_row').click(function() {
    ????
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function() {
  $("div.price_row").click(function() {
    selprice("<?php echo $price_options_array[$price_counter]['price'] ?>", "<?php echo $price_counter ?>");
  });
});
```

I wouldn't necessarily advise it however. Another approach is to put the necessary date in a place you can query it at runtime. For example:

```
<div class="price_info")
  <div class="price"><?php echo $price_options_array[$price_counter]['price'] ?></div>
  <div class="counter"><?php echo $price_counter ?></div>
</div>
```

combined with CSS:

```
div.price_info div.price, div.price_info div.counter { display: none; }
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
  $("div.price_row").click(function() {
    var price = $(this).children("price").text();
    var counter = $(this).children("counter").text();
    selprice(price, counter);
  });
});
```

Dynamically generated Javascript can sometimes get a bit messy.

You can also use [jquery.data()](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data) instead of using child elements. You just need to construct the class attribute correctly in PHP to include the necessary data.

Comment: FYI, typo in there '<div class="price_info")'

Comment: +1: I was writing the same solution as you but you came up with it first! Very good :)

Comment: It appears his price_counter is inside a non-listed PHP loop so your first example looks like it wouldn't work.

Comment: thanks for the time to write this all out for me, i will study it and see how i can best use this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Move your $price_options_array to a javascript array.

```
'var price_options = ' . $price_options  // or however you do it in PHP
```

And when you make your div inside your loop add an extra tag with the price_counter (pc)

```
"<div pc='". $price_counter . "'class="price_row" <?php echo $parameter; ?>>"
```

The "pc" variable will then be accessible in the jquery loop, as will the price_options info

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.price_row').click(function() {
     var pc = $(this).attr('pc');
     var price = price_options[pc]['price'];
     selprice(price, pc);
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

PHP:

```
<script language="text/javascript">var price_options = <?php echo json_encode($price_options_array); ?></script

for ( $y = 0; $y < $prices; $y++ )
{
  echo '<div class="price_row" id="price_' . $y . '">Foo</div>';
}
```

And in jQuery:

```
$('div.price_row').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    selprice(price_options[id], id);
});
```

This is untested but it should give you a rough start.